# Keycloak - UserModelDelegate setters are not called

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

i am working with Keycloak v4.8.3.

Im currently trying to implement a UserStorageProvider with an import strategy. Im following the documentation:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_development/index.html#import-implementation-strategy

This is my createAdapter method:

```java
   protected UserModel createAdapter(RealmModel realm, String username) {
    UserModel local = session.userLocalStorage().getUserByUsername(username, realm);
    if (local == null) {
        local = session.userLocalStorage().addUser(realm, username);
        local.setFederationLink(model.getId());
        local.setEnabled(true);
        local.setFirstName("test");
        local.setLastName("test");
    }
    return new UserModelDelegate(local) {
        @Override
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            System.out.println(username);
            super.setUsername(username);
        }
        @Override
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            System.out.println(email);
            super.setEmail(email);
        }
    };
}
```

On login, the user adapter gets created and imported to the keycloak interal database. When i try to change the Email address on the account page, the setEmail() method is never called. Keycloak just updates the interal database.

I need to change the Email address in an external system aswell.
How can i keep my external storage in sync?

Comment: May be you can try keycloak Event Listener SPI. And there you can listen for User Creation, Updation and deletion events (Which will also provides you the user representation). And do necessary updates there.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: See my answer. Please try it and report if it is working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up not implementing it at the time, but as @monzonj asked for it i investigated the problem again. The key seems to be to implement the ImportedUserValidation interface

```java
public class CustomUserProvider implements ImportedUserValidation {
    /*ImportedUserValidation*/
    @Override
    public UserModel validate(RealmModel realm, UserModel user) {
        return new CustomUser(user);
    }
}


public class CustomUser extends UserModelDelegate { 
    public CustomUser(UserModel delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        super.setFirstName(firstName);
        // Put your code here...
    }
}
```

Im not sure if this is the right way to do it, but a quick test showed, that this will call the setter when you try to change your first name on the account management page.

EDIT: We are now using keycloak v8.0.2

Comment: Hey, it does work. Thank you! I don't know if this is the proper way (seems it's a bug anyway), but it works for me. I'm using latest Keycloak 9.0.0

Comment: It doesn't work using Keycloak 16.0.0. :(

Comment: Can't confirm this yet. I am still using 15.0.2. But the official documentation has since been [updated](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/16.1/server_development/index.html#importeduservalidation-interface). Turns out this was the right way to do it, and should still work!